# what is the criteria that oracle follows to auto collect stats on user schema tables in 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

As per Oracle documentation its said it collects statistics for "all objects" in database. But, it does not specify anywhere that it collects for user specific schemas.

1) What is criteria it follows for auto collection of statistics on user specific schemas.
2) Is there any detailed explanation in metalink which explains how it is done.

Appreciate your valuable response on it.

Thanks,
Mir

Comment: "Before the maintenance window closes, automatic collection assesses all objects and prioritizes objects that have no statistics or very old statistics." so if you give a window of an hour, it'll do as much as it can in that hour - based on the objects that are the worst off

Answer (score 0):

The default statistics gathering process works for all schemas, including user schemas.  Statistics collection is difficult but basically boils down to when it gathers statistics and what statistics it gathers:

1. **WHEN** AutoTasks gather statistics during specified maintenance windows (usually 10PM every day).
2. **WHAT** The `STALE_PERCENT` preference determines when to gather statistics on a table or index.  By default, if 10% of the rows change statistics will be gathered.

But there are lots of exceptions.  Fixed object stats, dictionary object stats, and system statistics (about system performance), are only gathered manually.  And tables can be locked to not have their statistics altered.

You can read more details in the [Optimizer Statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/sql.html#GUID-5F4A2BE8-BC42-4734-B1F1-4C3BD57DAB6F) section of the Database Concepts Guide, or the [Optimizer Statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tgsql/optimizer-statistics.html#GUID-0A2F3D52-A135-43E1-9CAB-55BFE068A297) part of the SQL TUning Guide.

There are several ways to determine when statistics were last gathered.  Per object, you can look for the `LAST_ANALYZED` date column in views like `DBA_TABLES` and `DBA_INDEXES`.

To see when statistics auto tasks *should* run, there are lots of `DBA_AUTOTASK_*` views.  Those views are difficult to understand, there are many ways a task can be disabled.  (I wish Oracle had just used `DBMS_SCHEDULER`).  TO see when statistics tasks *were* run, see the views `DBA_OPTSTAT_*`.

It's a *huge* topic, and this answer is only a high level overview.